# WebRTC PeerConnection doesn't start

Tags: android, webrtc, voip

Mainly WebRTC works fine, but for times to times, some calls is failed. For example, one of twenty calls didn't established, because PeerConnection doesn't start to work.

Lets see about correct work flow on Caller side.

```
-> create offer
-> (sdp observer) getting SDP
-> (peer observer) start gathering candidates
-> (peer observer) adding candidates to SDP
-> set local description with type - offer
-> (signaling) sending SDP
   **** accepting call in other side ****
-> (signaling) receive answer SDP
-> set remote description with type - answer
-> (establishing call)
-> ...................
```

And for clarifying things, i want to show about call flow on Callee side. But I think it's just same flow for every WebRTC application, and not just for my question.

```
-> (signaling) receiving  SDP offer
    *****  accepting call  ****
-> set remote description type offer
-> create answer 
-> (sdp observer) getting SDP
-> (peer observer) start gathering candidates
-> (peer observer) adding candidates to SDP
-> set local description with type - answer
-> (signaling) sending SDP answer
-> ...................
```

And now, we are confident with correct call flow. Here is problem. From time to time, WebRTC failed call, because PeerConnection.Observer receiving nothing into onIceConnectionChange (PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState). So when call failed and when successful I received identically log from device, with only one difference. **In case of call failed, PeerConnection.Observer state, didn't change his state from NEW to CHECKING! Why this happens?**

---

As I said before, it happens only time from time. But still don't understand what is wrong? Because there only one difference between calls, it's PeerConnection change observer state. Maybe I'm using only single RELAY candidates for establishing call, maybe I so quick gathering candidates?

Comment: You are using vanilla ICE (not trickle ICE)? Does the failure sometimes happen for the same endpoints with the same network conditions (specifically NATs), or with different endpoints?

Comment: @mattm using vanilla Ice and same EndPoint in devices.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mattm already mentioned, big chance this has to do with `ICE`. Do you have a `STUN/TURN` server? If not, try [here](http://numb.viagenie.ca/). Make an account and when creating your `peerconnection` use `numb.viagenie.ca:3478` as an `ICE` server.

Outside your local network you have to deal with stricter firewalls, a `STUN` server can "punch holes" (open ports) to allow a peer to peer connection between clients. When using `WebRTC` in production you need one. Don't worry there are tons of public ones or you can host one yourself if you want to.

When making a connection between clients behind a strict `NAT` (happens a lot on cellular and school/company networks) you usually can't connect them peer to peer. That's where `TURN` comes in, it's a relay server that lets all clients send their data/media through it.

The `TURN` protocol also implements the `STUN` protocol, so if you use a single `TURN` server you're good to go. When you scale up to large amounts of clients you may need to think about hosting more than one.

Comment: I'm already use Google sample STUN server. Anyway I think it's another reason problem.

Comment: @GensaGames A STUN server or a TURN server? You need a TURN server to cover all network types.

Comment: Hi, maybe here still problem. I'm using only Google STUN URI.

Comment: But how I make call before. If my connection support handover and switching network in call.